# Convert to ARC - LLVM compiler 3.0 Error

Tags: xcode, llvm, automatic-ref-counting

I opened up an older project of mine and chose `Convert to Objective-C ARC` from the Edit/Refactor menu. I am getting the following error:

```
Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 Error

Error in format of file: /Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-fkjvtdsoypoyrdcedtarbtypupor/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/ProjectName.build/ProjectName-arc.migrate/remap
```

Is this one of those situations where I need to manually delete some files/folders in Finder and then try it again?   I just deleted everything in the "Build" folder of the project, then did `Product/Clean` and tried it again, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently you cannot have the target set to iOS Device when you "Convert to Objective-C ARC"

When I set the target to the simulator, I was able to convert to ARC with no errors.

Comment: Unbelievable, I could've been searching for this for like years if it weren't for your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Stupid freaking Apple. Fix your bugs.

Comment: @ObjectiveFlash: You're my hero.

Comment: For me the error never resolved in-spite of changing the target to simulator. I found that I was working on the wrong Xcode Build number Build 4C177. I switched to Build 4C199 and the error got cleared

Comment: After correcting all the 'Check' errors, I made a backup of my project just in case. The first time, the file-merge window was empty. After converting, I got this error, and the conversion seems to fail because Xcode left the calls to retain/release untouched (but set the ARC flag in the project). I'm trying next on a Lion machine with the latest Xcode...