# ARC conversion error after generating preview

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to convert my application to Automatic Reference Counting but when Xcode generates the preview I get this error:

```
/Users/alessandro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CroMAR-gwraklradkfapbguekcdgjignatm/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/CroMAR-Prefix-dlennltvfqdqsxbbvypkwlbqyvtn/CroMAR-Prefix.pch' file not found
```

I tried to clean the project, close Xcode, delete the derived data, add the .pch file to that directory but the error is still there and I cannot migrate to ARC. 
Any ideas?

Thanks
Ale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi solved the problem in that way. I noticed that the aforementioned problem was linked to the kind of problem reported in this discussion [Convert to ARC - LLVM compiler 3.0 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972960/convert-to-arc-llvm-compiler-3-0-error) thereby to solve the problem is to select the iOS simulator as target during the migration to ARC.

Answer (score 0):

Is your .pch file in the correct place as specified in your build settings?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have left any reference in code might be any variable which is pointing to the file and he is not getting it. just check it.